# how to get styles elements from database in Laravel 8

Tags: css, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to create dashboard branding, so I need to save color, font, and logo in database. I did save it to database. Now I want to access those data in  tag, navbar and css files.
This is my setting table which stores data.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Setting extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'logo',
        'font',
        'primary_color',
        'secondary_color',
        'ternary_color',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply access your desired data in any blade file by [sharing data with those blades](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views).

You can write this logic in your **AppServiceProvider**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\Models\Setting;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() 
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot() 
    {
        $setting_id = 1; // For example
        $setting = Setting::find($setting_id);

        View::share('color', $setting->color);
        View::share('font', $setting->font);
        View::share('logo', $setting->logo);
    }
}
```

Now, `$font`, `$color`, and `$logo` are available in all of your blade files.

Comment: how can I access these variables in css or scss files?

Comment: If you want to use them in css. You should write inline css in your blade files, but you cannot use them in scss.